# Angular - The type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I just copied this code from a tutorial

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      HttpInterceptor,
      HttpRequest,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpEvent,
      HttpErrorResponse
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, throwError, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';
    import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { LoginResponse } from './login-response.payload';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    isTokenRefreshing = false;
    refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.authService['getJwtToken']()) {
            this.addToken(req, this.authService['getJwtToken']());
        }

        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403){
            return this.handleAuthErrors(req, next);
          } else {
            return throwError(error);
          }
        }))
    }
    private handleAuthErrors(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (!this.isTokenRefreshing) {
            this.isTokenRefreshing = true;
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

            return this.authService['refreshToken']().pipe(
                switchMap((refreshTokenResponse: LoginResponse) => {
                    this.isTokenRefreshing = false;
                    
    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(refreshTokenResponse.authenticationToken);
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req, 
    refreshTokenResponse.authenticationToken));
                })
            )
        }
    }
    private addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, jwtToken: string) {
        return req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization',
                'Bearer ' + jwtToken)
            });
        }

    }
```

and i'm receiving this error

```
 'The type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
 Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
```

The error is caused here

```js
    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 404){
            return this.handleAuthErrors(req, next);
          } else {
            return throwError(error);
          }
        }))
```

What should I change to make it work?? (this the article btw https://programmingtechie.com/2020/04/05/build-a-full-stack-reddit-clone-with-spring-boot-and-angular-part-13/#Refresh_Token_Process_-_Step_by_Step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to analyze your code, however I was unable to understand the reason. If you are looking for a solution, you can add the return type `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` to the function signature as follows:

```
private handleAuthErrors(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
```

See the file check.js in a mock angular playground on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ye9r8z?file=app/check.ts)

This will solve your issue which comes from the usage of switchMap

see related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615681/rxjs-switchmap-mergemap-resulting-in-obserableunknown)

Also, according to [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5698), might be related to recent switch between rxjs versions. Try to restart IDE and clear cached node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Check out this similiar question:

> There are two problems here, you need to typecast return to your output, also finalize is missing from imports.

[Angular interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477494/angular-interceptor-type-observableunknown-is-not-assignable-to-type-obse)

I hope I could help you!

Kind regards
Sebastian

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't figure out the return type of `handleAuthErrors` because not all paths return a value. I don't know what the author intends to happen when the token is refreshing, but you can just return [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY).

```js
  private handleAuthErrors(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isTokenRefreshing) { ... }
    return EMPTY;
  }
```